# Error LNK2001 in Visual Studio 2017 when using static int

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, lnk2001

I'm doing some practice tasks for uni and I'm supposed to create `static int` field inside a class, but when I do so I get error LNK2001. When I change it to regular `int` the error does not occure. Can anybody help me please? Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Uczelnia {
public:
    virtual string getName() = 0;

    static int liczba_wszystkich_studentow;

};

class Politechnika:public Uczelnia {
public:
    Politechnika(string a, int b) {
        nazwa = a;
        liczba_studentow = b;
        liczba_wszystkich_studentow = +liczba_studentow;
    }

    string getName() {
        cout << "Politechnika: " << nazwa << endl;
        return nazwa;
    }

    ~Politechnika() {
        liczba_wszystkich_studentow = -liczba_studentow;
    }

private:
    string nazwa;
    int liczba_studentow;
};

class Uniwersytet :public Uczelnia {
public:
    Uniwersytet(string a, int b) {
        nazwa = a;
        liczba_studentow = b;
        liczba_wszystkich_studentow = +liczba_studentow;
    }

    string getName() {
        cout << "Uniwersytet: " << nazwa << endl;
        return nazwa;
    }

    ~Uniwersytet() {
        liczba_wszystkich_studentow = -liczba_studentow;
    }

private:
    string nazwa;
    int liczba_studentow;
};



int main() {
    Politechnika p1("Warszawska", 200);
    p1.getName();

    Uniwersytet u1("Warszawski", 600);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code file doing the actual definition of `static int liczba_wszystkich_studentow;`? What you show is only the declaration inside the class. You need something like `static int Uczelnia ::liczba_wszystkich_studentow=0;` in a code file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a linker error because you haven't initialized the static member. 
You just need to initialize it outside of the class.

```
class Uczelnia {
public:
//..
    static int liczba_wszystkich_studentow;
//..
};

int Uczelnia::liczba_wszystkich_studentow = 5;
```

There are some additional intricacies of being able to initialize `static const` integral types (like `int`) inside of the class, but with others you would typically initialize these static members in the source file outside of the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Within a class definition there are declarations of static data members not their definitions. Declared static data members within a class definition may even have an incomplete type. If a static data member is ODR used it shall be defined outside a class definition in some module. For example

```
int Uczelnia::liczba_wszystkich_studentow;
```

In C++ 17 you can use the `inline` specifier in a declaration of a static data member within a class definition.

For example

```
class Uczelnia {
public:
    virtual string getName() = 0;

    inline static int liczba_wszystkich_studentow;

};
```

In this case the code will compile provided that the compiler supports C++ 17..